# set -o vi in zsh: backspace doesn't delete non-inserted characters

Tags: terminal

I've used `set -o vi` on `bash` for a while.

However, I've started using `zsh`, and I've found that when I try to use the "delete" key (backspace for mac), it doesn't delete non-inserted text.

For instance: I can delete anything I've typed that using `delete`.

However, if I copy the command above (by the above arrow or `k`), I can't delete it.

For `vim`, I think I can do it with `set backspace=indent eol start` in `~/.vimrc`, but not sure how I can make that change with `vi`? Also unsure why it works in `bash` but not in `zsh`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Since zsh's vi-mode is not on-topic according to [help/on-topic], I've closed this question.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you for the welcome. However, I disagree that this is off-topic: to quote the help center: "Questions about plugins that replicate Vim's editing model in other editors (VSCode, Sublime Text, Emacs, etc.) may be on topic if they are about features or behavior that also exists in Vi". I don't see how replicating vi features in zsh is different from doing so in emacs.

Comment: I should have been more precise in my statement: the vi-like behavior is (probably) on-topic. Tweaking zsh's ZLE to make it more vi-like (or emulate `:set backspace=indent,eol,start`) is _not_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your `bindkey -v` command in your zshrc, put these commands:

```
bindkey "^H" backward-delete-char
bindkey "^?" backward-delete-char
```